# Delete all rows and keep latest x left

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a table like

```
entryid,  roomid
 1           1      
 2          55
 3           1
 4          12
 5           1
 6          44
 7           1
 8           3
 9           1
```

Now I would like to delete ALL entries where roomid = 1 and keep
the latest 3 from roomid = 1 left (best with just one command)

So finally entryid: 1 & 3 came deleted and entryid 6, 7, 9 keeps staying (for sure all other roomid will still stay)

**EDIT:
Thanks for help. Below I added my own solution, for everyone interested**

I started a [new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316721/mysql-delete-all-rows-and-keep-latest-x-left-part-2) how to bring that into ONE command. You may help me there.

Comment: yikes, please fix formatting and elaborate to make your question clearer.

Comment: Why does this need to be one command? I would use two.

Comment: now i use 2 :)
i work till now with two queries:

$sql_com = "SELECT id FROM `mytable` WHERE roomid = '3' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10,1";   

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);

$sql_com = "DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE id < ".$row[0];


but maybe it can be done better, just with one command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELETE` supports an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clause, so it is possible. However, due to `DELETE`'s referential restrictions and parameters of `LIMIT` you need two queries.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table  WHERE roomid = 1;
-- run only if count is > 3
DELETE FROM table WHERE roomid = 1 LIMIT total - 3;
```

Please note this will probably require an intermediary technology. I have shown the queries for reference.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I don't think MySQL allows a variable after `limit`.  You'd have to construct a dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: @Andomar Definitely, as I noted, this is more or less pseudo SQL to emphasis the 2 query approach. It would require a helping technology (say, PHP) to construct the dynamic queries.

Comment: i work till now with two queries:

// Delete older comments from that room > 100

  $sql_com = "SELECT id FROM `mytable` WHERE roomid = '3' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10,1";   
     if ($result = mysql_query ($sql_com)) {} else { echo ('Database SELECT ERROR, ' . mysql_error());} ;    
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);

  
  $sql_com = "DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE id < ".$row[0];
  if ($result = mysql_query ($sql_com)) {} else { echo ('Database SELECT ERROR, ' . mysql_error());} ;    

but maybe it can be done better, just with one command

Answer (score 1):

You can store the ids of the superfluous rooms in a temporary table, and delete based on that:

```
create temporary table tmpTable (id int);

insert  tmpTable
        (id)
select  id
from    YourTable yt
where   roomid = 1
        and 3 <=
        (
        select  count(*)
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.roomid = yt.roomid
                and yt2.id > yt.id
        );

delete  
from    YourTable
where   ID in (select id from tmpTable);
```

This results in:

```
ID  roomid
2   55
4   12
5   44
6   1
7   1
8   3
9   1
```

Comment: Nice if MySQL is the only technology at hand. But, IMO, this would be overkill if something else were available.

Comment: thanks.. but in my view if you have a large db it would need too much resources

Comment: @christian Muller: If you were deleting a million rows, a temporary table with one integer column would take up about 4 megabyte of RAM.  MySQL won't even notice :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @deleting = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE roomid = 1) - 3;
-- run only if @deleting is > 0
PREPARE stmt FROM 'DELETE FROM tbl WHERE roomid = 1 ORDER BY entryid LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE stmt USING @deleting;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
delete from TABLE 
where roomid=1 
   and entryid not in 
   (select entryid from TABLE where roomid=1 order by entryid desc limit 0, 3)
```

might work.

Comment: Will not work for mysql, can not refer to table to delete records in where. Need 2 query

Comment: ERROR 1093: You can't specify target table 'TABLE' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL guy here, but can t-sql do:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    TABLE A

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 3 entryID FROM TABLE WHERE roomID = 1 ORDER BY entryID DESC) B
    ON A.entryID = B.entryID 
WHERE       
    A.roomID = 1 AND
    B.entryID IS NULL
```

Then replace the select with DELETE TABLE FROM...

?

Comment: I'm afraid T-SQL is way more powerful than what MySQL allows.  This would generate the `ERROR 1093: You can't specify target table 'TABLE' for update in FROM clause` error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your Help.. I took them all together and use now this Solution :)
For me this Step is closed. Thanks.

```
// Delete older comments from room 1 (keep last 3 left)
// Step 1:
$sql_com = "SELECT id FROM `mytable` WHERE roomid = '1'";
$result = mysql_query ($sql_com); $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);       

// Step 2:
if ($num_rows > 3) {
  $sql_com = "SELECT id FROM `mytable` WHERE roomid = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3,1";  
  $result = mysql_query ($sql_com);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
}

// Step 3:  
$sql_com = "DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE roomid = '1' AND id < ".$row[0];
$result = mysql_query ($sql_com);
```