# Delete latest X records from mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am trying to `DELETE` latest 20 records from `mysql`.It means they would be last 20 records. So the problems is how can I do this? I have tried something like `delete from MyTable limit 20` but it deletes old 20 records(mean first 20 records).
I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312531/mysql-delete-all-rows-and-keep-latest-x-left) but the problem is , in `MyTable`, I have no primary or auto increment field.
I hope I explained well about my problem. Please guide for the solution.

Comment: You have no PK? You don't really have a table.

Comment: How can you identify the last rows, if there's no auto-increment field? Any column as Date_modified?

Answer (score 6):

You need a column that indicates which entries are old or new. This can either be a datetime colum or a increasing number or anything that indicates the order.

```
delete from MyTable 
order by some_column desc
limit 20
```

But the DB does not store the data in a specific order. You have to define one.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table with the same design as your old table, but with an extra, auto-incrementing column.

Count how many rows there are in the old table.  Call that *x*.

Let *y* = *x* - 20.

Insert into the new table everything from the old table (letting that auto-incrementing column auto-increment itself), but use

```
limit y
```

Now you have all the rows from the old table, except for the last 20.  Based on some ordering of the data.

Finally, drop the old table, and resolve to not create tables in the future that lack primary keys, otherwise you'll run into this problem again.

If there is a column that determines what date and time the row was inserted, you could order by that in ascending order when you do your insert.  If there isn't, then "latest 20 rows" doesn't have much meaning, as far as the database engine is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest for every DB system is to select columns into a new table a drop the old one and rename the new as the old one:

```
-- Assuming you have 100 records and want to drop the latest 30
create table `new_temp` as 
select * from `old_table`
limit 70;

drop table `old_table`;

alter table `new_temp` rename to `old_table`;
```

You can put some logic into the limit calculation but that should lead you.